# Resolving Many-To-Many relationship using Fact and single common key

Tags: data-warehouse, business-intelligence, modeling, dimensional-modeling

We have 3 tables as below:

1. DimTask
2. FactTask
3. DimReason

As the name suggests, DimTask and DimReason are dimensions and FactTask is a fact table.

DimTask table records details of task like "Description" and "Title" of task where a task just means an activity happened like maintenance/cleaning.
FactTask table records the measures of that task like fees,charges,time taken in minutes.
DimReason table records purpose of why that activity happened which could be multiple for a single task.

Now, DimTask and FactTask are connected/related through TaskID.
How do we handle the relation of DimReason in the model.

1. Should I create a bridge table and connect it to DimTask?
2. Can I connect DimReason to FactTask with same common key "TaskID"? Or is it a bad design practice.

Please help.

Comment: I can provide some data if it helps

Answer (score 0):

Without the data, it is tough

**Thought 1**

Looks like DimReason is not the dimension, rather it should be Fact

DimTask::TaskID > FactTask::TaskID ... the way your comments says as order header, FactOrderHeader type

DimTask::TaskID > FactReason(You called as DimReason)::TaskID ... they way your comments says as Order details, FactOrderDetails type

Note: Time bound activities are typically facts (with exceptions)

**Thought 2**
Multi-valued dimensions: https://www.kimballgroup.com/data-warehouse-business-intelligence-resources/kimball-techniques/dimensional-modeling-techniques/multivalued-dimension-bridge-table/

Hope this helps!